# Windows bash 'Cannot create property 'exitCode' on string 'autoupdate:' Installing Heroku CLI/Toolbelt

Tags: bash, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, heroku-cli

I am attempting to install the Heroku CLI/Toolbelt on an bash shell version 4.3.48(1) (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) running on Windows 10.  I'm entering `wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh` in the command line, and after the packages download I'm getting the below:

```
Preparing to unpack .../heroku_6.14.24-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking heroku (6.14.24-1) ...  
Setting up heroku (6.14.24-1) ...
+ which heroku
+ LOCATION=/usr/bin/heroku
+ echo heroku cli installed to /usr/bin/heroku
heroku cli installed to /usr/bin/heroku 
+ heroku version
▸    Cannot create property 'exitCode' on string 'autoupdate:'
```

And then it just takes me back to the command line.  If I try `heroku --v` or any other heroku CLI command I get this same error

```
 ▸    Cannot create property 'exitCode' on string 'autoupdate:'
```

I can't find any record of this error code anywhere online.  Any thoughts?  I really do not know where to start here, usually a good search at least sets me on the path but I have crickets here.  Let me know if any further details are required.  FWIW the toolbelt was working as of a few days ago, I just had to uninstall and reinstall my bash shell due to an unfortunate incident with Linuxbrew so am rebuilding everything from scratch.

Comment: same prbolem, should be a recent bug

Answer (score 0):

this is fixed but the CLI might have trouble updating. Delete `~/.local/share/heroku` and run `heroku update` and it should be fixed.